# query return data on clinet (ex: HeidiSQL) but return empty from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, heidisql

I have a query like that

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT('MAX(IF(`TraineeID` = ', `TraineeID`, ',"P","A"))AS ID', `TraineeID`)
) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_attn_temp;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date,"%d-%m-%Y")AS Date, ', @sql, ' 
FROM tbl_attn_temp
GROUP BY tbl_attn_temp.Date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

When I execute this query in a mysql clinent software (Here i use HeidiSQL) it returns data as bellow
[image]

But when I execute this query in phpmyadmin it returns empty data. 
Have a look here
[image]

Now how can I solve this issue.

Comment: works just fine, check the screenshot, `EXECUTE stmt` # Rows: 15`, try different web client or get results directly from your script

Comment: what is the data type of Date column in your db ? Is it date or int ?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?